# String index out of range with eclipse search and replace

Tags: eclipse, search, editor

I get this strange error as shown below. Any clue? I am matching lines like `aaaa        \` and I want to have `aaaa \`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`\s+` matches **all** [white spaces](http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.10/lib/pods/perlrecharclass.html#white_space) characters 1 or more times. So the extra space in search string is useless although not wrong. However, the search string could be also just `\s+\\` or perhaps better `[ \t]+\\` which avoids the deletion of line terminators.

The mistake resulting in the error message is in replace string.

Also in replace string the backslash is the escape character which means that the next character should be interpreted as literal character. A literal backslash character must be coded with `\\` in replace string like in search string.

There is just a single backslash at end of the replace string having no more character. Therefore this backslash escapes a character not being defined. The code of Eclipse does not handle this special error case with a single backslash at end of a replace string which should result in an error message because of an invalid replace string or the single backslash at end of replace string is interpreted as literal character instead of an escape character.

Eclipse interprets this single backslash as escape character for next character not existing and access nevertheless the character at index 3 of replace string although the replace string has only 3 characters with last character at index 2. As a result the low level routine which checks out of bounds access on strings outputs the error message

```
String index out of range: 3
```

The correction is the usage of a valid replace string which is here  `\\` with two backslashes.